# Issue when trying to set one of div as selected in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have following [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-boyd-j3pho).

I'm trying to store a value in my state and every time the user goes to the previous step he can see what he has selected and after that he can change and move on to the next step.

At the first step, everything works good. For example, the user selects the second text and proceeds to the next step, and when he returns to this step, he sees that the second text has already been selected...

The problem is with the second step, I write all the same, but it doesn't work for the second step. When I am clicking on one of the div's in second step nothing was happened. There is no error. Please help me to figure out what's the problem

Here is my code.

App file

```
    export default function App() {
     const [selected, setSelected] = useState(1);
     const [term, setTerm] = useState(1);

     const [current, setCurrent] = useState(0);

     const [data, setData] = useState({
       firstName: "bob",
       lastName: "Forest",
       age: 47
     });
      const steps = [
        {
          title: "Package Choose",
          content: (
            <PackageChoose
              setCurrent={setCurrent}
              data={data}
              setData={setData}
              selected={selected}
              setSelected={setSelected}
            />
         ),
          id: 0
        },
        {
          title: "Term",
          content: (
           <Term
            setCurrent={setCurrent}
            data={data}
            selected={term}
            setTerm={setTerm}
            setData={setData}
        />
          ),
          id: 1
        },
        {
          title: "Last step",
          content: <LastStep setCurrent={setCurrent} data={data} />,
          id: 2
        }
      ];
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>{steps[current].content}</div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

first step package choose file

```
    const PackageChoose = ({
      setCurrent,
      data,
      setData,
      setSelected,
      selected
    }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, packageType: "choice" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={1}
              selected={selected}
              onSelect={setSelected}
              text="text 1"
            />
          </div>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, packageType: "select" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={2}
              selected={selected}
              onSelect={setSelected}
              text="text 2"
             />
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => setCurrent(1)}>Next</button>
        </div>
      );
   };
```

second step Term file

```
   const Term = ({ setCurrent, data, setData, term, setTerm }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => setCurrent(0)}>Prev</button>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, termType: "30 day" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={1}
              selected={term}
              onSelect={setTerm}
              text=" term text 1"
            />
         </div>
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setData({ ...data, termType: "90 day" });
            }}
          >
            <SelectCard
              id={2}
              selected={term}
              onSelect={setTerm}
              text="term text 2"
            />
          </div>
          <button onClick={() => setCurrent(2)}>Next</button>
            </div>
      );
    };
```

SelectCard  file , in this file I am using `onSelect`

```
   const SelectCard = ({ id, selected, onSelect, text }) => {
      const myClassName =
        id === selected
          ? Styles.selectCardWrapperActives
          : Styles.selectCardWrapper;

      return (
        <div className={classNames(myClassName)} onClick={() => onSelect(id)}>
          <div> {text} </div>
        </div>
      );
     };
```

Please help me to understand how can I fix this problem in my code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code.

Your issue in props that you passed.

before: `setTerm={setTerm}` , now: `setSelected={setTerm}`

https://codesandbox.io/s/little-leftpad-3owuu

Answer (score 0):

You use variable "ssetTerm" on second step, it's misspelled.

Variable "setTerm" would be undefined, so it's not a function.

Comment: Just typography issue, I edited